# Proving by using inequality of triangle

Tags: inequality, triangles

suppose that points a and b are from different sides of a line m. Find a point y on line m such that the absolute difference of the YA and YB is maximal. Show proof.

Comment: What do you struggle with here? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am having trouble proving it. I know that if the points are  reflected over line m and construct line AB' and A'B. Marking the intersection on line m as point Y. I also know that it will only be maximum if and only if line m is an angle bisector.

Comment: I use geogebra in locating point Y.

Answer (score 0):

From $\triangle AYB$, we have  $ AB \ge \lvert YA - YB \rvert $.

Thus the maximum value would be $AB$, if we can show there can be equality for some $Y$.  From the cosine law, 
$$AB^2 = YA^2+YB^2-2\cdot YA \cdot YB \cdot \cos \angle Y \to (YA-YB)^2$$
when $\angle Y \to 0$.  Thus the value of $AB$ is never reached, but we can come arbitrarily close as we take $Y$ farther away from $A, B$ on either side of the line.